# MS Edge svg zoom

Tags: css, svg, zooming

svg format icons and I use zoom for **chrome** and **IE** to resize it to 85% and `-moz-transform: scale(0.85);` for **FF**, but in Edge it doesn't seem to work is there another way to do it in **Edge** ?

```
.myIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    zoom: 85%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
    background: url('../myIcons.svg') no-repeat -110px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
.myIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: url('../myIcons.svg') no-repeat -110px 0;
    /* zoom: 85%; Don't need this if you're using the cross browser codes below*/ 

    transform: scale(0.85); /* (Modern Browsers Universal Code including Edge) */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85); /* (Old versions of Firefox) */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85); /* (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera.) */
    -o-transform: scale(0.85); /* (Old versions of Opera) */
    -ms-transform: scale(0.85); /* (IE 9 and below) */
}
```

Comment: transform: scale(0.85); helped